# Set Checkbox to Checked with JavaScript after page Load

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, listener, onload

I've got a small challenge in trying to set this checkbox element on my page to checked, after the page loads:

`<input type="checkbox" id="1403317">`

**Challenges:**
1. This `<input>` can only be called by its **id** since there's no **name** attribute set.
2. The JS code to do this cannot be placed inside the `<head></head>` tag - I don't have access to that part of the code in this use case so this must work somewhere in `<body></body>`.

Here's how I've tried to do this so far (before the closing `</body>` tag), but with no effect. Is something wrong with my syntax?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("1403317").checked = true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: try this `document.getElementById("1403317").checked = "checked";`

Comment: Seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/13gbuw24/. If you are using HTML4 though there could be an issue with naming as IDs have to start with a letter (https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id)

Comment: i think my original code is fine, as is the suggestion from @will-hamic below (so i'm marking it as the right answer) - but i believe there's something else in the parts of this web app's code i don't have access to is superceding this function - so in the end i couldn't get it to work :(

Comment: Since your script is at the bottom of the body, you should be able to get away with omitting the `onload` and just running it directly. This should eliminate any clashes with other code replacing your handler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for. It works correctly in the snippet.

```js
window.onload = onPageLoad();

function onPageLoad() {
  document.getElementById("1403317").checked = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="1403317">
```

Answer (score 4):

try this one maybe ?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#1403317').attr('checked', true)
};
```